# React component shows the same image after passing as a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

[image]

The above is what I want to achieve.

To do this I typed the following code.

serviceSection.tsx

```
import { HomeService } from '../../../molecules/homeServices/homeService';
import capsuleViolet from '../../../../assets/images/homePage/homeServices/capsule_violet1.svg';
import sphereViolet from '../../../../assets/images/homePage/homeServices/sphere_violet1.svg';
import coneGreen from '../../../../assets/images/homePage/homeServices/cone_green1.svg';
import ringOrange from '../../../../assets/images/homePage/homeServices/ring_orange1.svg';
// import { ReactComponent as Calender } from '../../../../assets/images/homePage/homeServices/calender-front-color.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Megaphone } from '../../../../assets/images/homePage/homeServices/megaphone-front-premium.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Shield } from '../../../../assets/images/homePage/homeServices/sheild-front-color.svg';

import styles from './_index.module.scss';

const ServicesSection = () => {
  const serviceData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Increased Efficiency',
      descrption:
        'Our platform streamlines the process of managing clients, scheduling appointments, and delivering consulting services, reducing administrative overhead and freeing up more time for billable work.',
      firstColor: 'rgba(255, 175, 81, 0.26)',
      secondColor: 'rgba(255, 91, 100, 0.25)',
      img: <Megaphone />
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Enhanced Marketing',
      descrption:
        'Our platform includes marketing tools to help you reach new clients and build your brand, making it easier for you to grow your business and increase your reach.',
      firstColor: 'rgba(247, 235, 147, 0.25)',
      secondColor: 'rgba(255, 140, 21, 0.24)',
      img: <Megaphone />
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Data Security',
      descrption:
        'Our platform uses secure protocols and data storage to ensure that client information and other sensitive information remains confidential and protected.',
      firstColor: 'rgba(210, 252, 121, 0.31)',
      secondColor: 'rgba(136, 190, 141, 0.26)',
      img: <Shield />
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Data Security',
      descrption:
        'Our platform uses secure protocols and data storage to ensure that client information and other sensitive information remains confidential and protected.',
      firstColor: 'rgba(210, 252, 121, 0.31)',
      secondColor: 'rgba(136, 190, 141, 0.26)',
      img: <Shield />
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: 'Increased Efficiency',
      descrption:
        'Our platform streamlines the process of managing clients, scheduling appointments, and delivering consulting services, reducing administrative overhead and freeing up more time for billable work.',
      firstColor: 'rgba(255, 175, 81, 0.26)',
      secondColor: 'rgba(255, 91, 100, 0.25)',
      img: <Megaphone />
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      title: 'Enhanced Marketing',
      descrption:
        'Our platform includes marketing tools to help you reach new clients and build your brand, making it easier for you to grow your business and increase your reach.',
      firstColor: 'rgba(247, 235, 147, 0.25)',
      secondColor: 'rgba(255, 140, 21, 0.24)',
      img: <Megaphone />
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className={styles.sectioncontainer}>
      {/* images */}
      <img className={styles.sphereViolet} src={sphereViolet} alt="" />
      <img className={styles.capsuleViolet} src={capsuleViolet} alt="" />

      <img className={styles.coneGreen} src={coneGreen} alt="" />
      <img className={styles.ringOrange} src={ringOrange} alt="" />

      <h1 className={styles.toptext}>Let us take care your</h1>
      <h1>
        <span className={styles.consulting}>CONSULTING</span>{' '}
        <span className={styles.toptext}>problems</span>
      </h1>
      <p className={styles.subtext}>
        Scalable solution that will help you grow your business. Trust us to
        provide a robust and reliable platform for all your consulting needs.
      </p>

      <div className={styles.servicecontainer}>
        {serviceData.map((data) => {
          return (
            <HomeService
              key={data.id}
              title={data.title}
              description={data.descrption}
              firstColor={data.firstColor}
              secondColor={data.secondColor}
              image={data.img}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export { ServicesSection };
```

homeService.tsx

```
import classes from './_index.module.scss';

type homeServiceProps = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  firstColor: string;
  secondColor: string;
  image: any;
};

const HomeService = (props: homeServiceProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={classes.cage}
      style={{
        background: `linear-gradient(180deg, ${props.firstColor} 0%,${props.secondColor} 100%)`
      }}
    >
      {/* <div>{props.image}</div> */}
      {props.image}

      <h2 className={classes.title}>{props.title}</h2>
      <p>{props.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export { HomeService };
```

But when I render I get the same image in each component

It seems like it repeats the first image in the serviceData array

[image]

What can I do to solve this

I tried changing the order of the array items

Comment: why serviceData has 6 item while ui show 3 item?

Comment: No
Actually I showed only the first row in the screen shot. Another 3 items are under that. they also have the same image

Comment: can you share your code on sandbox?